# I sent 2 emails on 28/02 thaey still ongiong!

Tags: civimail

On the 28/02/2024 at 18hr, I sent 2 mailings which are still in progress, there is one at 87% and the 2ᵉ has not even started. These emails have been running for over 2 weeks, and they still have not been delivered. We are using an OVH individual server and sending via SMTP. Any ideas on ho to avoiding this blockage and how to get the emails to be sent immediately.  thank you!